# Connected and disconnected proofs

Tags: real-analysis

> a.) The Cantor set $\mathbb{F}$ is wildly disconnected. Show that if
>   $x,y \in \mathbb{F}$, $x\ne y$, then there is a disconnection $A,B$ of
>   $\mathbb{F}$ such that $x\in A$, $y\in B$.
>
> b.) Show that the set $$A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:0<y\leq x^2, x\ne
>  0\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$$
>
> is connected in $\mathbb{R}^2$. However there does not exist a
>   polygonal curve lying entirely in $A$ joining $(0,0)$ to other points
>   in the set.

How can I prove these? I know how to proof that the Cantor set is disconnected but I do not know how to prove a nor b.

Comment: I'm curious about the wording of (a), in particular the part *Show that if the Cantor set* $\mathbb C$ *is wildly disconnected and ...* Leaving aside the issue of what "wildly disconnected" means, is this really one of your assumptions? If the Cantor set is not wildly disconnected", it seems pointless to assume this, as anything can be proved from contradictory assumptions. However, if the Cantor set is wildly disconnected, it would seem to me that a less confusing wording would be something like "Using the fact that the Cantor set is wildly disconnected (which you don't have to prove), ..."

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro maybe I should roll back the edit I made. Maybe it will make more sense that way. Tell me if it does?

Comment: It's better the way I see it now. Better still (but I don't know if you want to do this, as it will move the question up to the front) would be something like "Show that the Cantor set $\mathbb F$ is wildly disconnected in the sense that if ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINTS:

(a) Show that if $x,y\in\Bbb F$ with $x<y$, there is a $u\in(x,y)\setminus\Bbb F$; then let $A=[0,u)\cap\Bbb F$ and $B=(u,1]\cap\Bbb F$.

(b) One way to show that $A$ is connected is to let $p=\langle 0,0\rangle$ and to note that if $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\setminus\{p\}$, there is a path from $\langle x,y\rangle$ consisting of the vertical line segment from $\langle x,y\rangle$ to $\langle x,x^2\rangle$ (which is degenerate of $y=x^2$) followed by the arc of the parabola from $\langle x,x^2\rangle$ to $p$. Thus, $A$ is the union of connected sets all having the point $p$ in common. One way to show that each of these paths is connected is to parametrize it as a continuous image of $[0,1]$.

To finish (b), show that $A$ does not contain any straight line segment containing $p$. (It may be easier to think of this in terms of the contrapositive: if $S$ is a straight line segment containing $p$, then $S\nsubseteq A$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian, I am going to attempt it now using your hints.

Comment: @Q.matin: Feel free to ping me if you get completely stuck.

Comment: Brian, I am having trouble understanding the hint in part b. You think you can elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Q.matin: A straight line segment containing $p$ lies an a line whose equation is $y=ax$ for some $a$. Since $p$ is the only point of the $x$-axis in $A$, $m\ne 0$. $A$ is symmetric about the $y$-axis, so we may as well assume that $m>0$. The line $y=mx$ intersects $y=x^2$ at $x=m$, and for $0<x<m$ we have $x^2<mx$: the straight line is **above** the parabola and therefore not in $A$.